# GWT String.replace not working

Tags: java, regex, string, gwt

I've to replace everything between two strings in GWT. For example,

In The string `"<script> something ... start .... </script>"` I want to replace everything between `start` and `</script>`.

I used `theString.replaceAll("start.*?</script>", "")` but nothing happens.

I tried this in a Java program it replace everything from `start` but this doesn't happen in GWT client side code.

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Do you assign the result from the `replaceAll` to a new `String` variable ?

Comment: yes, I do assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
theString = theString.replaceAll("(?s)start.*?</script>", "");
```

As there can be new lines in your input in Javascript snippet, `(?s)` will make DOT match new lines as well.

Equivalent Javascript regex:

```
theString = theString.replace(/start[\s\S]*?<\/script>/, "");
```

Comment: Exactly. One more question, I don't want remove the `</script>` from the string, how do I do that?

Comment: @Kaushik: You can just use: `heString = theString.replaceAll("(?s)start.*?</script>", "</script>");`

Comment: Got another solution `replaceAll("(?s)start.*?(?=</script>)", "");`

Comment: @anubhava Since GWT converts the code to javascript above regex doesn't work in GWT hosted mode. Do you know what would be the regex in javascript? 
Thanks.